# Some buttons to submit with default actions others to prevent default

Tags: javascript, html

I understand how to stop default action with preventdefault(), but I have not found a way to let some buttons default to their original submit action while preventing other buttons. I would think that 'break' would work, but not so. Can someone assist me?
Thanks,

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var clickedID = this.id 
    
    if (clickedID == 'admin_configs') {
        break     
    }
    
    else if (clickedID == 'btn_get_cfg') {
        msg='Your Configuration has been Retrieved'
        rslt = {
            btn_click: clickedID,
            data: $( "#btn_select option:selected" ).text()
        }
        populateForm(rslt,msg)
    
    }})
```

Comment: Which path is supposed to prevent default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to prevent default where you have the `break` currently printed, you can just use `preventDefault` there. You just have to make sure to call it on the event itself, which is the function argument.

```
$(".btn").click(function(event) {
    var clickedID = this.id 
    
    if (clickedID == 'admin_configs') {
        event.preventDefault();     
    }
    
    else if (clickedID == 'btn_get_cfg') {
        msg='Your Configuration has been Retrieved'
        rslt = {
            btn_click: clickedID,
            data: $( "#btn_select option:selected" ).text()
        }
        populateForm(rslt,msg)
    
    }
})
```

Comment: This works. I appreciate your assistance.